# From a list of ranges and another list of values find the range they lie

Tags: python

I have a list of ranges with start and end values along with corresponding normalized values which need to be fetched.
There is another list which needs to be checked in the list of ranges where they lie and get the corresponding normalized value.

I have this list:

```
[{
    'id': 1,
    'created_on': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 30, 8, 20, 38, 737757, tzinfo = < UTC > ),
    'created_by_id': 1,
    'tonnage_start_range': 1.2000,
    'tonnage_end_range': 2.0000,
    'normalized_tonnage': 1.4300
}, 
{
    'id': 2,
    'created_on': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 30, 8, 20, 38, 863579, tzinfo = < UTC > ),
    'created_by_id': 1,
    'tonnage_start_range': 2.0000,
    'tonnage_end_range': 16.0000,
    'normalized_tonnage': 6.4300
},
...]
```

And another list like this `[1.4, 10.6, 5.3, ...]`

I need to get the normalized_tonnage value for each in the above list.

```
{
    1.4: 1.43
    10.6: 6.43
    5.3: 6.43
}
```

I can run a for loop each time and compute this for each value using two for loops.
But I wish to write an optimal code.

Using space is fine. Just that using the brute force is not good.

So here is one for attempt

Edit :

I mentioned earlier with two for loops which one can see is brute force.
This is a part of a production level task. I can't use brute force there so I asked a qn on SO.

```
tonnage_map = {}
for range in ranges: 
    for value in tonnages: 
         if value >= range.get('tonnage_start_range') and value <=  range.get('tonnage_end_range'):
              tonnage_map[value] = range.get('normalized_tonnage')
         else:
              tonnage_map[value] = 0
```

Comment: You should probably show us your attempt, else this isn't very different  from other questions that get closed because they look like a homework question.

Comment: I still don't understand how list1 & list2 relates. Please clarify. (Edit - Finally understood from your reply to the answer below)

Comment: @HjSin list one has ranges start and end , so we need to get the value from list 2 , determine which range the value lies and get the normalised tonnage of that value from list2.

Comment: @AkshayHazari yup got it.

Comment: @UltraInstinct I had commented on that a brute force solution is not optimal with two for loops, if you want me to write that I have added it here. I don't think that adds any value. Just some SO mandates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Binary Search** within the ranges, might be your best option.

[Note: Untested code]

```
ranges = [                                                    
    {"start": x["tonnage_start_range"],                       
     "end": x["tonnage_end_range"],                           
     "value": x["normalized_tonnage"]}                        
    for x in data]                                            
                                                              
def binary_search(ranges, value):                             
    # If your min and max are always correct, I think you can get rid
    # of the below.
    if len(ranges) == 1:                                      
        if ranges[0]["start"] <= value <= ranges[0]["end"]:   
            return ranges[0]["value"]                         
        return None                                           
                                                              
    mid = len(ranges) // 2                                    
    if ranges[mid]["end"] < value:                            
        return binary_search(ranges[mid:], value)             
    elif ranges[mid]["start"] > value:                        
        return binary_search(ranges[:mid], value)             
    else:                                                     
        return ranges[mid]["value"]                           
                                                              
                                                              
print({x: binary_search(ranges, x) for x in [1.4, 10.6, 5.3]})
```

Comment: Yup changed my code to use binary search seems like best option for now.